# Whats the alternative for redshift Extract datatype

Tags: azure, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

What is the alternative for Extract in Azure Datawarehouse, we are using datepart right now but it does not work with from, so what can be a straight forward alternative for extract??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the equivalent of Redshift's [`EXTRACT`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_EXTRACT_function.html) is [`DATEPART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), as listed in the supported T-SQL functions of [Azure DWH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-reference-tsql-language-elements)

> DATEPART ( datepart , date )

e.g. the RedShift query

```
select salesid, extract(week from saletime) as weeknum
from sales 
where pricepaid > 9999 
order by 2;
```

Has the equivalent in T-SQL as

```
select salesid, DATEPART(ww, saletime) as weeknum
from sales 
where pricepaid > 9999 
order by 2;
```

i.e. `DATEPART` does not use `FROM` but instead is a function with 2 parameters - the first being the PART and the second the Date/Time to which to apply the function.

Comment: yeah am using this basically, thanks for the quick response.